# How to use google plus domain api

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I can call any Google+ API from the Google API Explorer, but any Google+ Domain API says "You do not have permission to execute this method." and returns next error:

403 Forbidden

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "forbidden",
      "message": "Forbidden"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

The same issue I have when use google+ domain .net api library.

Does Google+ Domain API work? Are there some live examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most likely reasons for getting this error with the Domain API are:

1. You don't have the Domain API enabled in the developer's console. You need to enable it separately from the Google+ API.
2. You aren't using it with a Google Apps account, but with a regular GMail account, or your Apps admin hasn't enabled Google+ for the Apps domain.

Comment: means domain api is only for paid user ?

Comment: The Domain API is only for Google Apps Domains (and only usable inside an Apps Domain). Most of the ways to get an Apps Domain require paying, but not all.

Comment: @Prisoner Google Apps are now paid-only (note that only free accounts created before December 2012 are still free), check this for more info: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120